# Call function after call service completed

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a function to call service

```
private callService() {
   this.functionOne();
   this.functionTwo();
   this.functionThree();
}

private getOtherInfo() {
   // pure sync here
   this.getId(this.user['data']);
   this.getType(this.name['data']);
}
```

I want the execution order is run `callService` first then run `getOtherInfo`.
However I found that the code can't reach the second function.

The functions inside `callService` are somehow like

```
private functionOne() {
    this.user['loading'] = true;
    this.service['user'].get().subscribe(data => {
    this.user['data'] = data;
   }
}

private functionTwo() {
    this.name['loading'] = true;
    this.service['name'].get().subscribe(data => {
    this.name['data'] = data;
   }
}
.....
```

So I changed the function as

```
private callService(): Promise<any> {
     return Promise.resolve() => {
      this.functionOne();
      this.functionTwo();
      this.functionThree();
     });
}
```

In `ngOnInit()` I call

```
this.callService().then(()=> this.getOtherInfo());
```

However the second function is still not reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all this can be solved with observables without the need for promises...

you'll want to change your three functions to be like:

```
private functionOne() {
    this.user['loading'] = true;
    return this.service['user'].get();
}

private functionTwo() {
    this.name['loading'] = true;
    return this.service['name'].get();
}
```

and then your callService to be like:

```
private callService(): Promise<any> {
     forkJoin(
      this.functionOne(),
      this.functionTwo(),
      this.functionThree()
     ).subscribe(([user, name, fnThreeData]) => {
       this.user['data'] = user;
       this.name['data'] = name;
       //whatever with fnThreeData
       this.getOtherInfo();
     });
}
```

don't try to mix promises and whatnot, rxjs provides all the functionality you neeed. you'll be facing an uphill battle in angular if you don't buy into rxjs.

Comment: I have had absolutely zero problems with using promises in angular. Zero. Whether you use rxjs or not is personal preference. I will admit, rxjs does have some good functionality when it comes to expensive autocomplete lookups (ie: search). I like the syntax of promises better and they are more of a standard now. Lots of libraries are returning promises (more so than libraries are returning rxjs observables)

Comment: Well the angular dev team and every angular project I’ve ever worked with shares my view on this. RXJS underlies several angular core services and is tightly intertwined with the framework. Besides promises have many many shortcomings that RXJS solves (lazy loading, multiple emissions and so on). In simple apps promises might do the trick but in a more complex environment you’ll be happy you switched to RXJS. And tbh, promises are a dying standard. They were the big thing but they’re being replaced by RXJS

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean we have onNext. I also want onError and onCompleted to log simple messages. Thanks for the nice help.

Comment: If you want to do it individually within the functions, you use the catchError and the finalize operators respectively, for the overall you can just use the error and complete handlers of the subscribe. For simple logging use the tap operator

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't look correct. `functionOne`, `functionTwo`, etc... aren't actually returning a promise. They actually aren't returning anything at all. You've got `.subscribe` but you never actually do anything with it. If you wrap your functions in a promise and resolve them correctly, you should be able to await all of them without any issue:

Example:

```
private functionOne() {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        this.user['loading'] = true;
        this.service['user'].get().subscribe(data => {
        this.user['data'] = data;
           resolve();
        });
    });
}

private functionTwo() {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        this.name['loading'] = true;
        this.service['name'].get().subscribe(data => {
            this.name['data'] = data;
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

private callService(): Promise<any> {
     return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
      await this.functionOne();
      await this.functionTwo();
      await this.functionThree();
     });
});
```

Here's an example of how to structure it (this question isn't really angular specific)

```js
function functionOne() {
 return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
   setTimeout( () => resolve('return from function 1'), 1000);
  })
}
function functionTwo() {
 return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
   setTimeout( () => resolve('return from function 2'), 1000);
  })
}

async function callAllFunctions() {
 const result1 = await functionOne();
  console.log(result1);
  const result2 = await functionTwo();
  console.log(result2);
}

callAllFunctions().then( () => console.log('finished'));
```

Comment: You mixed promise and Async together. It is hard to follow actually it isn’t working not sure why?

Comment: async is just a way to flag your function so that await can be leveraged. Returning promises in a function automatically make the function awaitable.

Comment: Okay. I think that why the code is not working. Say I have three functions. The two of them are asynchronous. The third one is a synchronous. How can I chain them together? The third one needs data from the first two functions. I googled a lot of. It seems all are talking about asynchronous methods.

Comment: The first of chunk I provided may not work as it's an example how to do it. The code provided in your question is incomplete so I can't make that work without the missing code which is why I provided the second chunk of code to show you how to go about it from scratch.